# Calculating Accrued Interest of Bonds

Tags: fixed-income, programming, bond

I am trying to calculate the accrued interest for a set of Treasury Bonds. I am comparing the answer from the code below with that for the 1st Bond(row) [over here](https://app.box.com/s/6i3vae7lb02n6glam7vwts7qpuc44q2w). In the link the AI is `0.061` whereas from the Python code I get `0.125` and am therefore trying to understand where I'm going wrong. I use the formula for AI available [here](http://www.riskencyclopedia.com/articles/bond-accrued-interest/).

```
#l contains the months to maturity 
accrued_interest = 0
d_ordered = {}
l = [0]*59 # My set of Bonds (not included here) includes a 30 year to maturity Semi-Annual coupon bearing bond and hence l will have 59 periods
l[0] = 3 # I have a function (not included here) which calculates the difference in months between each of the coupon payments (and the settlement date and first coupon payment)
d_ordered[0] = l
coupon = 0.250
days_in_coupon_period = 180 #The Link contains half-yearly bonds
for i in range(0,1,1):
    months_to_maturity_array = numpy.array(d_ordered[i])
    for k in range(0,59,1):
        # Adding the AI associated with each period k
        accrued_interest = accrued_interest + ((coupon) * ((30*months_to_maturity_array[k]) /days_in_coupon_period))
    print('AI', accrued_interest)
```

Thank You

Comment: @haginile I kindly request your help in this question as you provided the document against which I am comparing the Accrued Interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

US Treasuries follow the Actual/Actual day count convention, so you can't make the assumption that there are 180 days in a coupon period.

Let's assume that the settlement date (T + 1 for US Treasuries) is 8/6/2015, the previous coupon date for a bond is 7/31/2015, and the next coupon date is 1/31/2016. Then the number of days in the coupon period is 184 days, and the accrual period is 4 days. The accrued interest, assuming a 5% coupon rate, must be $4/184 \times 5/2 = 0.054347826$.

Comment: Thank you once again. One thing I'm unsure of is how to set the settlement dates for each coupon payment. I've previously assumed its just 1 day after the coupon payment is due. And hence, if I were to have a 30 year to maturity bond, then the formula would be : $accrued interest = accrued interest from last period + (1/coupon period × coupon/2)$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Jojo There should be one settlement for all cash flows. If the pricing date is today, the settlement date is just the next business day after the pricing date.

Comment: Thanks. So, if there is a bond with 12 months to maturity and it has settlement date 8/6/2015 and has the same description as you described in you answer, **and** a coupon date on 7/31/2016, would the Accrued Interest for this bond be $0.054347826 + 4/184×5/2$? I'm sort of confused how to calculate the Accrued Interest for the next period.

Comment: @Jojo, sorry i'm quite confused... there's one accrued interest for each bond and for each settlement date. 0.054 IS the accrued interest. Why are you adding the other term?

Comment: Thank You. I have further questions about this calculation and have asked a separate question [here](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/19195/understanding-how-to-calculate-accrued-interest-of-bonds) to try and address these.

Comment: @haginile: Should the accrued days be 6, then 6/184? Thank you.